# R rbind and group by using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

I have the following data

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
year = c("2001","2001", "2001", "2001", "2002","2002", "2002", "2002"),
type = c("Animals", "Animals", "People", "People", "Animals", "Animals", "People", "People"),
type_group = c("Dogs", "Cats", "John", "Jane", "Dogs", "Cats", "John", "Jane"),
analysis1 = c(32.7, 67.5, 34.6, 56.5, 56.7, 78.5, 98.9, 87.3),
analysis2 = c(23.7, 89.4, 45.8, 98.6, 45.7, 45.7, 23.6, 23.6),
analysis3 = c(45.7, 45.7, 23.6, 23.6, 14.4, 45.4, 98.0, 12.2),
analysis4 = c(14.4, 45.4, 98.0, 12.2, 34.6, 44.3, 23.8, 16.3))
```

I'm using `rbind` to create new rows with some new calculations which you will see in the code below.

I want to know if there is a neater and faster way of doing this. I'm sure there must be...my data has around 30 years in it and around 60 variables, so to use the example I have developed here would take ages to write in the script on my real data:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(year =="2001") %>% 
rbind(c("2001", "People diff","John and Jane", 
            df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
            df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
            df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
            df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Jane'])) %>% 
  rbind(c("2001","Animals diff","Dogs and cats", 
            df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
            df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
            df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
            df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'])) -> data_2001


df1 %>% 
  filter(year =="2002") %>% 
  rbind(c("2002", "People diff","John and Jane", 
          df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
          df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
          df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Jane'],
          df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'John'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Jane'])) %>% 
  rbind(c("2002","Animals diff","Dogs and cats", 
          df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
          df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis2[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
          df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis3[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'],
          df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Cats'] - df1$analysis4[df1$type_group == 'Dogs'])) -> data_2002

rbind(data_2001, data_2002) -> final_data
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think your analysis is incorrect, unless it was intended this way. In your `rbind` you include data for two years with `df1$analysis1[df1$type_group == 'John']`, but bind them with only one year and call e.g. `2001`.

The fast and easy way can be to use `spread` and `gather` from `tidyr` package, e.g.

```
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  gather(analysis, value, -year, -type, -type_group) %>%
  group_by(year, type, analysis) %>%
  summarise( value = diff(value)) %>%
  spread(analysis, value)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. When I get a second I'll look at my error in the question and will amend. Just a final question - in the summary part of the code it's taking the row below and is subtracting from the row above. Is there a way to reverse that, so the row above is subtracted from the row below? Or would I need to reorder the rows in the data before applying the above code?

Comment: I think the easies way would be to make `type = factor(type, levels = c(...))` and then arrange by `type` depending on which order you prefer.